# CSS styled anchor tag button not working properly (fails occasionally)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, anchor

I have the following code.

I copied CSS [here](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/11/css-buttons-with-pseudo-elements/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>anchor button not working</title>
    <style>
        .a_demo_two {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color:#6fba26;
            padding:10px;
            position:relative;
            font-family: 'ChunkFiveRegular';
            text-align: center;
            font-size:12px;
            text-decoration:none;
            color:#fff;
            background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(100,170,30) 0%, rgb(129,212,51) 100%);
            box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #b2f17f, 0px 6px 0px #3d6f0d;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }

        .a_demo_two:active {
            top:7px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(100,170,30) 100%, rgb(129,212,51) 0%);
            box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #b2f17f, inset 0px -1px 0px #3d6f0d;
            color: #156785;
            text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
            background: rgb(44,160,202);
        }

        .a_demo_two::before {
            background-color:#072239;
            content:"";
            display:block;
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            padding-left:2px;
            padding-right:2px;
            padding-bottom:4px;
            left:-2px;
            top:5px;
            z-index:-1;
            border-radius: 6px;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #fff;
        }

        .a_demo_two:active::before {
            top:-2px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="controls_container">
        <a href="#" class="a_demo_two" onclick="reset_function()"></a>
    </div>

    <div id='test'></div>

    <script>
        var bet = 0;
        function reset_function() {
            bet++;
            document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= bet;
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I click the increase `button` it works sometimes and does not sometimes.

It appears as if there are few spot where when clicked the button does not work.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to solve this?

I am using **Chrome** and **Firefox**.

Comment: Seems fine to me: http://jsfiddle.net/3bfzE/

Comment: after looking at your link I realized that this code work when there in no text. but I still have the same issue with the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are missing some of your **HTML** markup. There's only one button on this page and it's only function is to reset something.

Now, because you are using anchor links as buttons, the default behavior would be to redirect you to the anchor's `href` attribute.

So, as described above, remove the `href="#"` attribute and your code should work fine.

Should you care to implement a library like `jQuery`, you'll be introduced to event methods that automatically ignore the default event (like submits and `href`s) using just a single line of script like:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Here's my version of your code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/yL7Hr/)

Comment: can accomplish same thing in native script without jQuery

Comment: Yes, here is Mozilla's version of avoiding default actions....
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.preventDefault

Comment: @DevlshOne  Hello there guys I am sorry to go back and forth. When I removed the href="#" the button worked fine in Firefox however I am still having some issues in chrome. Even after using return false I am having issue. I put return false at the end of reset_function() not sure if that was what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `href` attribute from `a`nchor tag and it should work fine.

Comment: I am so sorry to go back and forth with this. The problem is solved by your method in firefox however I am still having the issue in chrome for some reason.